# Store output of mysql select statement as python list

Tags: python, mysql, list, select, mysql-python

I have a very large table in mysql that I'm accessing through a python script, and I'd like the output of my select query to be stored as a list. Here's what I have:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='', user='', passwd='', db='')
cursor = db.cursor()

sqlselect = "SELECT desig FROM table WHERE num=0;"
desigs = cursor.execute(sqlselect)
print desigs
```

But this just gives me the number of rows in set which is nearly 250,000. Instead, I'd like it to print a list of each 'desig'. How can I do this?

Comment: `print [desig for desig in cursor]`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule you can't iterate on an integer ;)

Comment: That should be `cursor` and not `desigs` right after `execute` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` will return the number of rows modified or retrieved.

Once you've executed the query, run `cursor.fetchall()`, which will return you an array containing each row in your query results. That is, you get an array of arrays.

Edit: list! list of lists!! argh

Comment: Don't you mean list of lists?

Comment: @Barmar dang it, I had just used `array` to describe a list somewhere else, and it leaked into stackexchange, how embarrassing. I'll leave it up to teach myself a lesson.